# system-config-printer broken after update to 14.04

Tags: python, printing, gui, gobject

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 the dialog system-config-printer in gnome runs into problems when called from the command line:

```
sudo system-config-printer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/system-config-printer.py", line 72, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GObject # for TYPE_STRING and TYPE_PYOBJECT
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    raise ImportError('When using gi.repository you must not import static '
ImportError: When using gi.repository you must not import static modules like "gobject". Please change all occurrences of "import gobject" to "from gi.repository import GObject".
```

The problem persisted when I tried to change the suggested imports in the package, i.e.,

```
cd /usr/share/system-config-printer
sed -i 's/import gobject/from gi.repository import GObject/g' *.py
sed -i 's/gobject/GObject/g' *.py
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying system files is not a good idea, instead check first that you have the latest version of the corresponding [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/system-config-printer-gnome):

```
dpkg-query -W system-config-printer-gnome
```

It should return:

```
system-config-printer-gnome    1.4.3+20140219-0ubuntu2.1
```

Then try to re-install the package using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall system-config-printer-gnome
```

Comment: Indeed I ran an older version of the tool. I wonder why apt-get upgrade did not update this package... Btw the tool now complains "There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'Success'." but this might be another story. Thanks.